# Символьные массивы в Си

Tags: c

Есть символьный массив типа char размером 10, в него вводятся последовательность цифр, которая не должна превышать 6, максимум вводимых цифр 10, если вводится больше 6 цифр, то обработать первые 6. После ввода символов нужно каждый символ проверить они равны нулю или единице, если хотя бы один из символов не равен 0 или 1, то вывести Number is wrong.

**Вот сам код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    char str[10] = {0};
    scanf("%6s", str);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1') {
                printf("Number is wrong");
                break;
            }
        }
        system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Если ввожу 6 и больше, то он всё правильно делает, если меньше 6 цифр, то уже просто так выводит number is wrong. Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста.

Comment: И какой символ в строке вызывает попадание в эту ветку? Чем по-вашему заполнено свободное место в строке, если ввести меньше 6 символов? Может вы не различаете символ с кодом 0 и символ с кодом 48 цифра ноль `'0'`?

Comment: Я использую символьный массив, потому что в задании так сказано. Грубо говоря суть задания в том, что вводим последовательность должна быть только из двоичных символов и если один из символов не является символом 0 и 1 то вывести number is wrong. И программа почти правильно работает, то есть если я введу 6 и больше цифр, он все правильно определяет. А если меньше 6 то уже сбоит, а вот почему не могу понять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1') {
                printf("Number is wrong");
                break;
            }
```

этот цикл идет по всем 6-ти символам. а у вас конец строки может наступить раньше. 
я не уверен в правильном срабатывании `scanf("%6s", str);`т.к. он должен ждать от вас именно 6 символов. лучше просто ввести строку или читать посимвольно.
а в цикл добавить условие на раннее завершение цикла при конце строки.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 6&&str[i]!=0; i++) {
                if(str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1') {
                    printf("Number is wrong");
                    break;
                }
```

еще я бы проверил что там находится в массиве. просто выведя его на экран